# Passing parameter to ng-click function with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please see code below:

```html
<div>
  <div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item" ng-click="c.selectItem(note.sys_id)" 
       ng-repeat="note in data.notes">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
        {{note.title}}
      </h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">
        {{note.sys_id}}
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

in the output I can see that note.sys_id is getting printed. However, I need to pass this to the ng-click function on top. I tried below code, but no result:

```js
 ng-click="c.selectItem(note.sys_id)"
 ng-click="c.selectItem({{note.sys_id}})"
```

Comment: Where is the `c` code? Does `ng-click="alert(note.sys_id)"`work?

Comment: nope, alert does not work. Also c is from controller.

Comment: Have you verified that you can hit the function without any arguments? If you're not hitting it at all, then the `c` is your problem

Comment: it working with $index, however I would like to change it to use id instead of index. c is not a problem here.

Comment: I've successfully used `ng-click` on the same element where the `ng-repeat` variable (in your case, `note`) is defined without any issues, so that shouldn't be the problem. Some random things you can try: list `ng-repeat` _before_ `ng-click` in the list of attributes; try using `note['sys_id']` instead of dot notation in case something weird is happening with the expression interpolation; pass in the whole `note` object reference instead of just the sys_id property.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/1q8mdb3z/

```
ng-click="c.selectItem(note.sys_id)"
```

should work for you. Make sure your function is correct. I'd assume your scope is something to the effect

```
$scope.c = {
    selectItem = function(id) {
      // do something with id
    }
}
```